# Execute Windows batch command in Jenkins for Java Program

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-build-flow

I am facing error when creating a Build on Jenkins.
Following are the steps i have done.

**Step1:**

1. Create Folder
   "Java_Project"
2. Create File
   "Hello.Java"

   ```
    public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

            System.out.println("Hellow World..." + i);

        }
    }}
   ```

**Step2**

1. Go to my CMD and type below commands.

a) **javac Hello.java**

b) **Java Hello**

and it print below result successfully.

D:\AWS_Assingnment\jenkins_assingnment\Java_Project>java Hello

Hellow World...1

Hellow World...2

Hellow World...3

Hellow World...4

Hellow World...5

**Step 3**

Now i go to my Jenkins and create a simple Build as follows.
Fig 1
[image]
Fig 2
[image]
Fig3 **I AM ON WINDOWS**
[image]
**Enter Below Commands**

**cd d:\AWS_Assingnment\jenkins_assingnment\Java_Project**

**javac Hello.java**

**java Hello**

Fig4
[image]

**Step 4**
Create Build
Fig 5

[image]

### **I AM FACING BELOW ERROR**

[image]

Gurus, Your Kind Support is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Resolved.

I edit the Build file
[image]

And change the batch file as below

[image]

**d:**

**cd \AWS_Assingnment\jenkins_assingnment\Java_Project**

**javac Hello.java**

**java Hello**

[image]